# Smartsheet python SDK Add row with cell link

Tags: python, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am trying to add a new row to an existing sheet with date columns.  Some of the cells in the new row hyperlink to other sheets, this works fine.  But there are other cells that I want to link_in_to from other sheets.  I keep getting an "attributes are not allowed for this operation" error.

there was a comment from an old smartsheet community post indicating that cell links don't work in the 1.1 API.  But we are well past that, and the 2.0 documentation implies that it should be possible.

Has anyone else seen this or solved it?

```
row_a.cells.append({
    'column_id': status_columns['Exp Start'],
    'value': None,
    'linkInFromCell': {
        'columnID': project_columns['Start'],
        'rowID': project_rows[1],
        'sheetID': map_of_sheets[this_project]},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property must be set to an `ExplicitNull` (so that it is serialized as null in the JSON body), like this:

```py
        cell = smart.models.Cell()
        cell.column_id = col_id
        cell.link_in_from_cell = cell_link
        cell.value = smart.models.ExplicitNull()

        row = smart.models.Row()
        row.id = added_row.id
        row.cells.append(cell)

        action = smart.Sheets.update_rows(sheet.id, [row])
```

Check out `test_regression.py` in the `tests/integration` folder, test case `test_link_in_from_cell` shows the technique.

Comment: A celllink can only be added to an existing cell, so you will have to do this in two steps, add the row/cell first and then update the cell setting just the celllink and explicit null value (no other changes can be made at the same time).